# Disabling only scroll-bar feature

Tags: javascript, css

I want to disable scroll-bar functionality for chrome and don't want to hide the scroll-bar by giving **overflow:hidden**.
The scroll-bar should be visible

I want something like this: http://prntscr.com/ai5y9k

Any help would be great!!

Answer (score 0):

use `overflow: auto`

that will display a scroll bar only when necessary (i.e. the content is higer than the window)

Comment: thanks for the answer, actually the the initial page has  scroll-bar, but as soon as another div which is position absolute , appears on the top of it  , I still want that scroll feature but not hide it .For this ans I'm still able to scroll

Answer (score 0):

Closest you will get to, is to enforce the body to be no larger than the window then tell the scroll bar to always be present.

```
body { 
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  overflow:scroll;}
```